# Shortcodes/BBcode regular expression

Tags: php, regex, shortcode, regular-language, bbcode

I have an issue with writing the correct regular expression.

I'm using shortcodes in my system and they are working just great. I've sorted it's attributes etc., but now I want to use a shortcode inside of the other shortcode.

Here's how I'm preparing the regular expression:

```
$attributes_regexp = "([^\]]*?)";
$inner_content_regexp = "(.*?)";
$flags_regexp = "im";
$regexp = "/\[$shortcode$attributes_regexp\]$inner_content_regexp\[\/$shortcode\]/$flags_regexp";
preg_match_all($regexp, $content, $found_occurrences);
```

Here's how an example of a ready regular expression looks like:

```
\[file([^\]]*?)\](.*?)\[\/file\]
```

And here's a bit of HTML that have to be analysed:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<h2>Test page</h2>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong>Some</strong> content</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor.&nbsp;</p>
<p>Dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>[file id=290 type=link][file id=283 type=image width=100 height=100][/file][/file]</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
<p>[file id=289 type=image][/file]</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it's getting correctly only the last one changing it to image, but the previous one is taken like

> **[file id=290 type=link]**[file id=283 type=image width=100 height=100]**[/file]**

Instead of two separate ones

> **[file id=283 type=image width=100 height=100][/file]**

and

> **[file id=290 type=link][/file]**

Any ideas how this can be sorted?

Many thanks,
Tomasz

Comment: So you are using regex to replace something like `[file id=289 type=image][/file]` with an img tag that has the proper attributes?

Comment: Yes, and it's working very well. But Now I need to replace one inside of the another. Problem is that they are both the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data only brakes the XML standard with the tag separators `[` and `]` instead of `<` and `>` you could turn the data into XML and use a XML-parser for further analysis:

```
$regex = "/(\[{$shortcode}.+\[\/{$shortcode}\])/";
if (preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches)) {
    array_shift($matches); //removes $matches[0], which contains the whole $content again
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        //The following line should turn your data into valid XML
        $xml = str_replace(['[', ']'], ['<', '>'], $match);
        //Some XML parsing like:
        $xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
        //...
    }
}
```

Like this you do not have to invent the wheel again.

Comment: Thanks, based on your solution I've redesign my code as didn't want to write the whole thing from scratch. Now I'm firstly looking for tags thanks to your regexp and than I process them with mine regexp and reverse the array to work from right to left and it fully working. Thanks!